# Raspbian wpa_supplicant fails, which service to (re)start?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, services, wpa, init.d

I'm using Raspberry Pi 2 installed with Raspbian (Debian Wheezy) ~ Release date: 2015-02-16.

Every now and then `wpa_supplicant` dies on me and usually when I'm remote and I cannot do anything other then physically either reboot the Pi or start the `wpa_supplicant` process through the Terminal.

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ps ax | grep '/sbin/wpa_supplicant' | grep -v grep
 1814 ?        Ss     0:29 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /var/run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -W -D nl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

Is there a *service* that can be (re)started in order to get it going?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command to restart networking entirely, including wpa_supplicant, is this:

```
sudo systemctl restart networking.service
```

As a side note, you should be able to hit the `<tab>` key after you start typing the name of a service and your shell will autocomplete the name of the service, assuming you've typed in enough to make it unique. That saves you from accidentally using the name `network.service` which is incorrect as of Jessie, and I assume so for Wheezy. If the `<tab>` key didn't autocomplete at all, hit it again to see a list. If no list appears, there is no service name that starts with what you typed.

Also, wpa_supplicant might not be crashing if your only symptom is that your Pi disconnects from Wifi and doesn't reconnect. Make sure your `/etc/network/interfaces` file includes a line `allow-hotplug wlan0` right before the `wlan0` interface. It's the default on Jessie, I'm not sure about Wheezy. Sometimes you'll lose your connection due to interference and the Pi won't reconnect if it isn't configured to.

This answer is intended to help anyone who might stumble across it in the future, since the original question is a few months old now and it's author might not need the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

2020 and buster =>

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure
```

... assuming it's using wifi on wlan0 as per iwconfig

Comment: that seems to do the deed very nicely!

Answer (score 1):

`systemd` was included in Debian Wheezy, So you can use the following command to restart the network:

```
systemctl restart network.service
```

or

```
systemctl restart networking.service
```

Comment: No such file or directory for network.service

Answer (score -1):

You could use `sudo ifdown wlan0` followed by `sudo ifup wlan0` to bring the network back up.
Then use `ifconfig wlan0` to check if you got an IP assigned.

Comment: I got following message : `running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not re-enable some interfaces`, that did _NOT_ help me to get my `wpa_supplicant` back either(

Comment: Yeah I didn't really know what the outcome of restarting the network service would be. Ifup and ifdown should do the trick though.

Comment: it doesn't, as `wlan0` never goes down at the first place, it's `wpa_supplicant` that's dies, I tried it anyways though..

Comment: You don't need to use the wpa_supplicant if you don't want to. You could try configuring the network settings in the network file where you load up wpa_supplicant

Comment: I'd prefer to use `wpa_supplicant` as it makes it a lot easier to switch networks (without modifying anything).